# Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'

Tags: powershell

I've never encountered this error in PowerShell before. Using an IDE it works, but it doesn't work in the Exchange shell window.

I can do this all day in C#, but for some reason it doesn't work in Powershell. I've seen a bunch of examples on the net saying I can't use the `+` in the `.Add()` method, as well as defining `$results` as an array and using `+=` with that, but none of those work.

I'd appreciate it someone could fix my code, but also tell me why this isn't working so that I can not make this mistake again.

The error message is

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId]
doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\bleh1.ps1:168 char:3
+ $results.Add($serverName + "|" + $totalDbs.ToString() + "|" + $activeDbs.ToSt ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~‌​~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~‌​~~~
    + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

To reproduce you only need to populate `$servers` with 2 or more Exchange server names

```
$servers = @("server1", "server2");

[int] $mountedDBs = 0;
[int] $dismountedDBs = 0;
$preferenceOne = 0;
$preferenceTwo = 0;
$preferenceThree = 0;
$preferenceFour = 0;
[int] $displayLineCount = 0;
$results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach($server in $servers)
{
    if ($server -ne "")
    {
        [Array]$values = Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server -Status;
        $serverTest = $server;
        Clear-Item Variable:mountedDBs
        Clear-Item Variable:dismountedDBs

        for($i = 0; $i -lt $values.Count; $i++)
        {
            #servername     totaldbs    activedbs   passivedbs  preferencecountlist     mounteddbs      dismounteddbs   dagname
            $serverName = $server;    
            $totaldbs = $values.Count;
            $temp1 = $values[$i].Mounted;

            if ($values[$i].Mounted -eq "true")
            {
                $mountedDBs = $mountedDBs + 1 | Out-Null;;
            }
            else
            {
                $dismountedDBs = $dismountedDBs + 1 | Out-Null;;
            }

            $activationPrefTemp = $values[$i].ActivationPreference;
            for($j = 0; $j -lt $activationPrefTemp.Count; $j++)
            {
                $temp1 = $activationPrefTemp[$j].ToString();
                if ($activationPrefTemp[$j].ToString().Contains($server.ToString()))
                {
                    $activationPref = $activationPrefTemp[$j];
                    [string]$activationPrefNumber = $activationPref;
                    [int] $index = $activationPrefNumber.IndexOf(",");
                    $activationPrefNumber = $activationPrefNumber.Remove(0, $index + 1);
                    $activationPrefNumber = $activationPrefNumber.Trim()
                    $index = $activationPrefNumber.IndexOf("]");
                    $activationPrefNumber = $activationPrefNumber.Remove($index);

                    Switch ($activationPrefNumber)    
                    {
                        1 {$preferenceOne = $preferenceOne + 1; break;}
                        2 {$preferenceTwo = $preferenceTwo + 1; break;}
                        3 {$preferenceThree = $preferenceThree + 1; break;}
                        4 {$preferenceFour = $preferenceFour + 1; break;}
                        default {$null}
                    }
                }
            }    
            $mountedDBs = $mountedDBs;
        }
        $activeDbs = $preferenceOne;
        $passiveDbs = $preferenceTwo + $preferenceThree + $preferenceFour;
        $results.Add($serverName  + "|" + $totalDbs.ToString() + "|" + $activeDbs.ToString() + "|" + $passiveDbs.ToString() + "|" + $preferenceOne + "," + $preferenceTwo + "," + $preferenceThree + "," + $preferenceFour + "|" + $mountedDBs + "|" + $dismountedDbs + "|" + $dagName);
        $displayLineCount = $displayLineCount + 1 | Out-Null;
        $preferenceOne = 0 | Out-Null;
        $preferenceTwo = 0 | Out-Null;
        $preferenceThree = 0 | Out-Null;
        $preferenceFour = 0 | Out-Null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing a find and replace of ' | Out-Null;'. Does your situation improve? Could you include more details on what is actually going wrong here?

Comment: Please check which of the variables you're trying to concatenate there contains the offending object (`$varname.GetType().FullName`).

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working, thank you for the help @MacroPower . You deleted your post so I do not know how to give you credit for answering?

You were right, because the $server variable was not explicitly typed as a string, the .ToString() cast was necessary.

```
[int] $mountedDBs = 0;
[int] $dismountedDBs = 0;
$preferenceOne = 0;
$preferenceTwo = 0;
$preferenceThree = 0;
$preferenceFour = 0;
[int] $displayLineCount = 0;
$results = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[String]"


foreach($server in $servers)
{
    if ($server -ne "")
    {
        [Array]$values = Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server -Status;
        $serverTest = $server;
        Clear-Item Variable:mountedDBs
        Clear-Item Variable:dismountedDBs

        for($i = 0; $i -lt $values.Count; $i++)
        {
            #servername     totaldbs    activedbs   passivedbs  preferencecountlist     mounteddbs      dismounteddbs   dagname
            $serverName = $server; 
            $totaldbs = $values.Count;
            $temp1 = $values[$i].Mounted;

            if ($values[$i].Mounted -eq "true")
            {
                $mountedDBs = $mountedDBs + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $dismountedDBs = $dismountedDBs + 1;
            }

            $activationPrefTemp = $values[$i].ActivationPreference;
            for($j = 0; $j -lt $activationPrefTemp.Count; $j++)
            {
                $temp1 = $activationPrefTemp[$j].ToString();
                if ($activationPrefTemp[$j].ToString().Contains($server.ToString()))
                {
                    $activationPref = $activationPrefTemp[$j];
                    [string]$activationPrefNumber = $activationPref;
                    [int] $index = $activationPrefNumber.IndexOf(",");
                    $activationPrefNumber = $activationPrefNumber.Remove(0, $index + 1);
                    $activationPrefNumber = $activationPrefNumber.Trim()
                    $index = $activationPrefNumber.IndexOf("]");
                    $activationPrefNumber = $activationPrefNumber.Remove($index);

                    Switch ($activationPrefNumber) 
                    {
                        1 {$preferenceOne = $preferenceOne + 1; break;}
                        2 {$preferenceTwo = $preferenceTwo + 1; break;}
                        3 {$preferenceThree = $preferenceThree + 1; break;}
                        4 {$preferenceFour = $preferenceFour + 1; break;}
                        default {$null}
                    }
                }
            }           
            $mountedDBs = $mountedDBs;
        }
        $activeDbs = $preferenceOne;
        $passiveDbs = $preferenceTwo + $preferenceThree + $preferenceFour;

        $results.Add($serverName.ToString()  + "|" + $totalDbs.ToString() + "|" + $activeDbs.ToString() + "|" + $passiveDbs.ToString() + "|" + $preferenceOne + "," + $preferenceTwo + "," + $preferenceThree + "," + $preferenceFour + "|" + $mountedDBs + "|" + $dismountedDbs + "|" + $dagName);
        $displayLineCount = $displayLineCount + 1 | Out-Null;
        $preferenceOne = 0; 
        $preferenceTwo = 0;
        $preferenceThree = 0;
        $preferenceFour = 0;
    }
```